# Json parsing losgstash

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, logstash

i can't parse this json with logstash... someone could help me?
seems like the way it is parsed can't be readed by logstash.
there is a ruby code to parse this?
I cannot extract the fields nested in the square brackets

```
    [
     {
      "capacity": 0,
      "created_at": "2021-04-06T16:18:34+02:00",
      "decisions": [
       {
        "duration": "22h16m4.141220361s",
        "id": 842,
        "origin": "CAPI",
        "scenario": "crowdsecurity/http-bad-user-agent",
        "scope": "ip",
        "simulated": false,
        "type": "ban",
        "value": "3.214.184.223/32"
       },
    .
    .
    .
{
    "duration": "22h16m4.195897491s",
    "id": 904,
    "origin": "CAPI",
    "scenario": "crowdsecurity/http-backdoors-attempts",
    "scope": "ip",
    "simulated": false,
    "type": "ban",
    "value": "51.68.11.195/32"
   }
  ],
  "events": null,
  "events_count": 0,
  "id": 12,
  "labels": null,
  "leakspeed": "",
  "machine_id": "N/A",
  "message": "",
  "scenario": "update : +63/-0 IPs",
  "scenario_hash": "",
  "scenario_version": "",
  "simulated": false,
  "source": {
   "scope": "Community blocklist",
   "value": ""
  },
  "start_at": "2021-04-06 16:18:34.750588276 +0200 +0200",
  "stop_at": "2021-04-06 16:18:34.750588717 +0200 +0200"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Require JSON
JSON.parse(yourString)
```

Would likely be what you're looking for.
The module is described [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)